# Retaining UNIQUE attribute fields after dissolving a shapefile

Tags: arcgis-desktop, merge, spatial-join

I tried the solution to "Dissolving shapefiles but retain attribute fields" but my original shapefile (3000 rows in attribute table) has many duplicate values in the field that I want to retain so that the merge overruns the field width. Is there a way to merge only unique field values in the merged attribute field?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a read of the article [HowTo:  Identify duplicate field values](http://support.esri.com/cN/knowledgebase/techarticles/detail/38700).

From there do the following:

- set your definition query for the layer you made to `FIELD NAME = 0`(this will identify all values that are unique.
- run your dissolve function on the data

Comment: What will happen to shape associated with field=1 ?